# powershell select-string preserve formatting of git log

Tags: git, powershell, formatting, git-log

**Is it possible to preserve formatting (specifically colour) of a string when piped through select-string?**

I'm using select-string to find entries with specific tags in a git log that's been pretty-formatted with some nice colours. Unfortunately the colour gets lost in the process, and I get something that looks like non-printing control characters scattered about. This happens even on the "line" property of the match-info object.

I've piped the output of the git log into Get-Member and it appears to be a vanilla System.String.

**Extra-details**:
(probably not important, but you can never tell)

powershell v4

git 1.9.5

The formatted git log command is:

```
git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(cyan)%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

I am vaguely aware that I may be able to do something similar with git log switches, and I'm looking into this, but for this question, assume I still need to pipe the output through powershell commands keeping the colours.

**Edit:**

Mangled output looks something like this (slightly sanitized). Unfortunately the unicode chars didn't survive emailing off the system in question.

```
* [0123abc[m -[33m (tag: build-1.0.3730)[m Some Comment [32m(5 hours ago) [1;34m<Author Name>[m
* [0123xyz[m -[33m[m Some other comment [32m(6 hours ago) [1;34m<Author Name>[m
```

According to www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html there is a control (escape) character in the output with codepoint U+001B, immediately preceding each left square bracket in the previous example, however these were removed by email clients.

Comment: Can you include the "mangled" output here as well? Preferably in some hex/binary output in case it contains any control characters/etc.

Comment: I'll have a go, I'll need to sanitise it a little, but will try to preserve any unicode/exciting chars as best I can.

Comment: The coloring is done via [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) embedded in the string, so your regular expressions needs to include these in order to preserve coloring.

Comment: @Ansgar, I'm not sure I understand. The regex passed to select-string? At the moment I'm simply searching for a plain string, then getting the "Line" Property of the Match-Info object, by which time the result is already as above.

Comment: Hmm... you're right. Perhaps something like [this](http://blog.fastconnect.fr/?tag=powershell) or like [this](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) might help.